# Elasticsearch nest 2.x - Search return null value

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an issue with elasticsearch nest 2.x client

I have a one model like this:

```
   public class ProductPrice 
{

    public string ProductImagePath { get; set; }
    public string VideoPath { get; set; }
    public bool ProfitRateIsSet { get; set; }
    public decimal? ProfitRate { get; set; }
    public decimal TLPrice { get; set; }
    public string SearchKey { get; set; }

}
```

And i wrote this code lines,

```
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        settings.PrettyJson(true);


        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);


 var createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("product-price")
        .Mappings(ms => ms
                        .Map<ProductPrice>(m => m.AutoMap())
                 );
        var response = client.CreateIndex(createIndexDescriptor);


   var request2 = client.Search<ProductPrice>(s => s
                .Index(ElasticConnect.Constants.Index.PRODUCT_PRICE)
                .Type(ElasticConnect.Constants.Type.COUCHBASE_DOCUMENT)
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .Query(q => q
                        .Term("productID", "210068468")
                )
        );
```

search is success to find product but productprice model properties always null.

Where am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: May you share index mapping?

Comment: `ProductPrice` in ES response contains e.g. `IsCabinet` property, but definition of class you shared, doesn't. How is that?

Comment: @Rob `
            client.Map<ProductPrice>(m => m
                     .Index(ElasticConnect.Constants.Index.PRODUCT_PRICE)
                     .AutoMap()
                 );` Is not that enough?

Comment: @muhammetsahin can you share the mapping json response as returned by `http://localhost:9200/{index_name}/_mapping/{type_name}`

Comment: @RussCam mapping json: [This web site link](https://jpst.it/Pq-V)

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the mapping where you have a top level `productID` property; there are 9 instances of `productID` but none of them are a top level property on the document.

Comment: First if you have [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) change your address to http://localhost.fiddler:9200 and see what is being requested and returning from the server. Second you model is not the same as the one in debug try adding attributes on your properties in model and naming them.